# When I run "git push" I get "tip of your current branch is behind its remote" but the current branche has no upstream tracking branch

Tags: git, github, push, git-branch, pull

I am working on this local branch X and when I try to push using `git push -u origin X` 
the error message is :

```
! [rejected]        X -> X (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to "********"
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I run : `git pull` 
And an error message also appear :

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> X
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a local branch named `X`, without tracking information, so there is no corresponding *upstream*.

Then you are trying to push it to `origin` as `X`. So far so good... but there is a branch in that remote with that name, so your push is only accepted if it is a fast-forward, which it is not.

When you do `git pull` you try to merge/rebase the tracking branch, but your `X` does not have one! so it fails.

You have basically two options:

1. Add the tracking information: as git helpfully prints in the console: `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/X X`, then `git pull`, `git status`, `git merge`, `git rebse`, `git push` without arguments will default to the tracking branch, and it will work as expected.
2. Kindly refuse to add tracking information. Then you must do the full commands: `git fetch origin`, then `git rebase origin/X` or `git merge origin/X`, and `git push origin X`.

Since you are trying `git push -u`, and `-u` means "add tracking information", I guess that you want option 1.

Comment: git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/X X did the job, at that point I just had to resolve the merge conflicts, commit and push

Comment: I think you mean to say git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/X X in 1.